# How can I set Visual Studio to automatically close the external exception source document when the the application is stopped?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

This is driving me crazy, but I am currently working on a project in which I typically have a library project open, as well as the Forms project that uses it.

When I run the Forms application from inside Visual Studio and an exception occurs in the library code, a tab opens up in the Forms project containing a second copy of the library source. I can't count the number of times I started editing the wrong one.

I realise that it sounds trivial, so if you think it's a stupid problem feel free to ignore it, but if you've ever had the same problem and found a solution, please let me know.

Comment: try deleting the .pdb file from wherever you are referencing your library project. Then I think VS won't be able to find the source file.

Comment: What do you mean by "second copy"? Why are there two versions of the library code?

Comment: @Cameron: I mean my library source files are open in the Library's Visual Studio project on my desktop.

Comment: Oh! I see. I've had that problem too :-) No solution, though...

Comment: @Rhumborl: hey, thanks for that suggestion, but didn't really work. Anyway, I guess what I'm really hoping for is some setting in Visual Studio that would either close the extra tab with the exception code, or even make it readonly or something so I stopped editing it by mistake. Maybe it's just something I'll have to live with

Comment: @Cameron: Thanks, I feel like less of an idiot to know that I'm not the only one, sucks that I can't change it though :P

Comment: Hard to guess what "second copy" might be.  Unless you are running *two* instances of Visual Studio, one for the library project and another for the winforms project.  You do realize that a Solution can have more than one project?  No need for two VS instances.

Comment: @HansPassant: That's exactly what I mean. And no, to be honest that idea didn't occur to me. Thanks, I'll try that.